# How to retrieve the remote IP address using Play! inside a docker container

Tags: playframework, docker, request, ip

I run a Play! application inside a docker container and I'm facing a problem. When I call the method `remoteAddress` on a request like this:
`request => request.remoteAddress`
I always get the IP address of the docker container instead of the user address IP.

What can I do in order to be able to retrieve the address IP of the user that made the request to my Play! application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the docker user-land proxy.
Check out these issues on the docker github
[Document how to get real remote client ip for service running in container](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15086)
[Disable Userland proxy by default](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14856)

I believe `--userland-proxy=false` is the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I tried to start docker with /usr/bin/docker daemon --userland-proxy=true but it does not change anything. Is it the right way to proceed?

Comment: @Simon you want to disable the proxy, not enable it. It is already enabled by default.

Comment: Yep indeed, but I tried with false not true, my bad. But apparently it works expect for a request made by the same host that started the docker container, that's why I said it does not change anything. I try with my server and I accept your response if it works ;)